# My background doesn't fade in, just loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

I have the following javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).load(function () {

        var images = ['image_1.jpg', 'image_2.jpg', 'image_3.jpg', 'image_4.jpg', 'image_5.jpg'];

        $('h1').fadeIn(2000, function () {
            $('body').fadeIn(3000, function () {
                $('body').css({
                    'background-image': 'url(images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Link to my (let´s call it a) site: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/46415927/index.html

The problem is that the background does not fade in after the text. Anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('body').hide();
```

first, as you can't fade something in that's already being shown.

so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(window).load(function () {

        var images = ['image_1.jpg', 'image_2.jpg', 'image_3.jpg', 'image_4.jpg', 'image_5.jpg'];

        $('h1').fadeIn(2000, function () {
            $('body').hide().fadeIn(3000, function () {
                $('body').css({
                    'background-image': 'url(images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: this will still cause the background image to appear without a fade in because the image will be set AFTER the body has been hidden/faded in

Comment: I already set the body to hide in the CSS. But do I have to reorder my code so it will first pick a random image and then fade it in?

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that about the CSS, in that case it should work and adding the `hide` shouldn't stop it from working either.

Comment: after reading your code properly, I think @cfs' answer is actually correct, I answered in a rush yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

You have your callback functions firing in the wrong order. The code as your wrote says "fade in h1 over 2 seconds. When that is done, fade in the body over 3 seconds. When that is done, set the background image for the body."

You'll want to hide the body and set the background image, then fade in the body, then fade in the `h1`. The code will be something like:

```
$('body').hide().css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});
$('body').fadeIn(3000, function () {
    $('h1').fadeIn(2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you would need to have the default css for the background element, body in your case, be opacity:0.

You are setting the background-image css property as a callback function after the body element has faded in. You would need to set that random background image first before initiating the fadeIn method.

Comment: [link]$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).load(function(){
 cache: true; 
 var images = ['image_1.jpg', 'image_2.jpg', 'image_3.jpg', 'image_4.jpg', 'image_5.jpg'];
 
 $('body').css({'background-image': 'url(images/'+images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});
 
 $('h1').fadeIn(2000,function(){
  $('body').fadeIn(3000);
 });
});
}); [/link] I did this, but still no luck

Comment: you don't need `$(document).ready()` and `$(window).load()`. As a matter of fact that might be part of your problem. Just use `$(document).ready()`. Also, fading in the `body` as a callback to fading in `h1` doesn't make sense since `h1` is *in* the `body`.